# detect method when user navigate back to application from setting screen in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am using below code to navigate user to setting screen to manually allow location permission :

```
 PermissionHandler().openAppSettings();
```

And once user allow this permission i am checking whether the permission is granted or not. If granted i will allow user to navigate to next screen.

```
 @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    checkPermission(); //this will check the status of permission when the user returns back from the settings page.
  }


  checkPermission() async {
    var location = Location();
    bool _permission = false;
    bool serviceStatus = await location.serviceEnabled();
    if (serviceStatus) {
      print("enable");
      _permission = await location.requestPermission();
      print("Permission result: $_permission");
      if (_permission) {
         // Navigate to next screen
      }else{
        print("permission not enable");
      }
    } else {
      print("not enable");
    }
  }
```

Problem is `didChangeAppLifecycleState` method always get called for any action on the screen. How should i detect the state when user navigate to app from background to foreground or navigate to screen from setting screen.
Below are the state but non of this is useful.

- `resumed`
- `inActivate`
- `paused`
- `detached`

Comment: check the AppLifeCycleState when didChangeAppLifecycleState is called, It can be inactive, paused, resumed, detached.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/AppLifecycleState-class.html

Comment: @Karthik thank you for the reply. ApplifecycleState.resume is called.But this flat is always called if i dismiss the location dialog also. What i actually want to detect is specific method or flag which detect background to foreground action

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code is missing just one thing: you are not making use of the `state` variable to check the current app's lifecycle state. You can simply use it to check the current app state before running the `checkPermission()` function.

```
@override
void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
  // If user resumed to this app, check permission
  if(state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
    checkPermission();
  }
}
```

Now `checkPermission()` will only be called if the current app's lifecycle state is `resumed`.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Resume state is also called when i dismiss the default dialog box for location permission and same state is called when i move application from background to foreground.

Comment: Not working :(, any clue?